# JS Firebase Auth wait for Init without clearing result for getRedirectResult()

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

One technique for waiting for Firebase Auth to initialize before proceeding it to do something like:

```
  this.firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged(_ =>{
    //Continue initializing your app
  } );
```

However, using this technique will actually check for a redirect result and log the user in, thus clearing the result for:

```
this.firebaseApp.auth().getRedirectResult()
```

Is there a way to verify that Firebase and Firebase Auth have been initialized, without clearing the Redirect Result?

Answer (score 0):

`onAuthStateChanged` listener should not clear `getRedirectResult` if there is an available result. I believe `getRedirectResult` will clear on `signOut`, or after it is called once.